# Can not get data from custom MySQL table in Adminhtml grid table

Tags: adminhtml, mysql

i'm using Magento 1.9.0.1.

I'm trying to display data from a custom MySQL table to a grid table in a custom admin panel page.

Here is the structure of the table from which i want to display the data.
The table is called - `VivasIndustries_SmsNotification`:

[image]

Right now i have this result:

[image]

As you can see no table is created and no data is displayed.

Now i'm going to show you what i have in my extension files:

I have in /app/code/community/VivasIndustries/SmsNotification/etc/config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <VivasIndustries_SmsNotification>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </VivasIndustries_SmsNotification>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <models>
        <smsnotification>
            <class>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>vivasindustries_smsnotification_resource</resourceModel>
        </smsnotification>
        <vivasindustries_smsnotification_resource>
        <class>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Model_Resource</class>
        <entities>
            <smsnotification>
            <table>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification</table>
            </smsnotification>
        </entities>
        </vivasindustries_smsnotification_resource>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <smsnotification_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                 <use>core_setup</use>
             </connection>
        </smsnotification_setup>
        <smsnotification_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </smsnotification_read>
        <smsnotification_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </smsnotification_write>
    </resources>    
    <events>
        <sales_order_save_after>
            <observers>
                <vivasindustries_smsnotification>
                    <class>smsnotification/observer</class>
                    <method>orderSaved</method>
                </vivasindustries_smsnotification>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_save_after>
    </events>
    <helpers>
        <smsnotification>
            <class>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Helper</class>
        </smsnotification>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
        <smsnotification>
             <class>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Block</class>
        </smsnotification>
    </blocks>
  </global>
  <adminhtml>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow Everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <vivas>
                                        <title>Vivas - All</title>
                                    </vivas>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
    </adminhtml>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <VivasIndustries_SmsNotification before="Mage_Adminhtml">VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Adminhtml</VivasIndustries_SmsNotification>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

Here is what i have in: /app/code/community/VivasIndustries/SmsNotification/Model/SmsNotification.php:

```
<?php
class VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Model_SmsNotification extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('smsnotification/smsnotification');
    }

}
```

Here is what i have in: /app/code/community/VivasIndustries/SmsNotification/Model/Resource/SmsNotification.php:

```
<?php
class VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Model_Resource_SmsNotification extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Initialize resource model
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('smsnotification/smsnotification','id');
    }
}
```

Here is what i have in: /app/code/community/VivasIndustries/SmsNotification/Model/Resource/SmsNotification/Collection.php:

```
<?php 
class VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Model_Resource_SmsNotification_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract{
    protected function _construct(){
        $this->_init('smsnotification/smsnotification');    
    }
}
```

**And last and maybe most important:**

Here is what i have in: /app/code/community/VivasIndustries/SmsNotification/Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Status/Grid.php:

```
<?php

class VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Status_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('smsnotification_grid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('id');
        $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
    }


    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('smsnotification/smsnotification_collection');
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }


    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
          $this->addColumn('id', array(
              'header'    => Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('ID'),
              'align'     =>'right',
              'width'     => '50px',
              'index'     => 'id',
          ));

          $this->addColumn('Receiver', array(
              'header'    => Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Receiver'),
              'align'     =>'left',
              'index'     => 'Receiver',
          ));    

          return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    public function getGridUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', array('_current'=>true));
    }
}
```

Here is what i have in: /app/code/community/VivasIndustries/SmsNotification/Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Status.php:

```
<?php

class VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Status extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_blockGroup = 'smsnotification';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_sales_status';
        $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Send SMS on Order Status Changes');

        parent::__construct();
        $this->_removeButton('add');
    }
}
```

Please help me out to display the data from `VivasIndustries_SmsNotification` and why now i get blank page, where is my mistake?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be missing two things to get your Grid to show up.

Add this file:

`app/code/community/VivasIndustries/SmsNotification/Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Status.php`

```
<?php
class VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Status extends     Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container
{

public function __construct()
{

    $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_sales_status';
    $this->_blockGroup = 'smsnotification';
    $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('SMS Notifications');
    parent::__construct();
}


protected function _prepareLayout()
{
   $this->setChild( 'grid',
       $this->getLayout()->createBlock( $this->_blockGroup.'/' . $this->_controller . '_grid',
       $this->_controller . '.grid')->setSaveParametersInSession(true) );
   return parent::_prepareLayout();
}

}
```

And this file:

`app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/smsnotification.xml`

```
<layout>
    <adminhtml_smsnotification_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="smsnotification/adminhtml_sales_status" name="smsnotification" />
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_smsnotification_index>
</layout>
```

In your `etc/config.xml`, add this in the `<adminhtml>` tag:

```
  <layout>
        <updates>
            <smsnotification>
                <file>smsnotification.xml</file>
            </smsnotification>
        </updates>
    </layout>
```

Comment: No.. no there was a mistake posting it here. There is no doube `<?PHP` tags in the real file and the problem is still the same.

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: When i do that i got error: Fatal error: Call to a member function getCollection() on a non-object in /home/superweb/public_html/store/app/code/community/VivasIndustries/SmsNotification/Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Status/Grid.php on line 18

Comment: On line 18 is the following content `$collection = Mage::getModel('smsnotification/smsnotification')->getCollection();`

Comment: Ok change that back then.  Quick question:  do you have an xml in app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/ for your extension?

Comment: Also post all of the files and content from your module's `Block` subfolders

Comment: No i don't have it. Maybe this can be the problem. What should i do then ? Thanks once again!

Comment: Two things.  I'll update my answer with them.  Also don't forget to accept my other answers if they helped :)

Comment: The only one file which is located in the `Blocks` is `Status.php` and i updated my question with it. The other one is `Grid.php` which is already in the question. Thank you once again!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20937/discussion-between-seanbreeden-and-the-lex).

Comment: I've done the edits by your was answer edit and i still have the same problem. Maybe i need to point something about this layout xml file in the config.xml file ?

Comment: Hello there Sean, can you please check this thing out: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/56243/creating-a-new-form-in-admin-panel-but-save-button-is-not-working We are kinda stuck in there! :D